# .ddl missing error when trying to install libs on Python 2.7 - Win 8.1

Tags: python, python-2.7, dll, pip

I am trying to install python 2.7 and my usual libs.

Python 2.7 is installed (and the shell seems ok) - my config : win8.1 64bits

Setuptools, pip and virtualenv were installed after that

Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 redistribuable is also  installed (to fix a [vcvarsall.bat] error), and I unistalled the basic 2010 Visual studio.

When I try to install my libs I get these popup errors:

- installation on the virtual env = MSvcr100.dll missing
- installation without env = python27.dll missing

Here is one sample trying to install psyopg2

```
        writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

        warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



            Error:

            ----------------------------------------
            Cleaning up...
              Removing temporary dir c:\users\xcpro\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_xcpro...
            Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in c:\users\xcpro\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_xcpro\psycopg2
            Exception information:
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:\Users\xcpro\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
                status = self.run(options, args)
              File "C:\Users\xcpro\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg\pip\commands\install.py", line 278, in run
                requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
              File "C:\Users\xcpro\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line 1229, in prepare_files
                req_to_install.run_eg

    g_info()
              File "C:\Users\xcpro\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line 325, in run_egg_info
                command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
              File "C:\Users\xcpro\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg\pip\util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess

    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
        InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in c:\users\xcpro\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_xcpro\psycopg2



I tried reinstallation, all possible things without success (except from downloading a dll, which seems to be risky...). Having spent 8hours in vain... any idea ?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat
```

Comment: Do you need to compile things yourself? If not, http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Well, it's a good question. Actually, not now for sure, but I'm a bit worry to be stuck later. In which occasions should I do the compiling myself.

Comment: Edit : It works but I am not able to use my virtual environnement any more